# Create 3 columns in HTML – left and right fixed width and middle elastic

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create three columns in html with the left column positioned at the left side of the screen and at fixed width, the right side positioned at the right of the screen and at fixed width and the middle column elastic and filling up the remaining width.
I'm trying to NOT use flex if that's possible.

What should the CSS look like?

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>

</div>
```

css

```
.container {}
.left {}
.middle {}
.right {}
```

Comment: Why not `flex`?

Comment: The old way is float. First right &left floatting, then middle . `overflow:hidden` will do the magic for middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created two simple examples. First one does not use `flex` as long as you don't want to use it.

Example using `calc()`

```css
.container > div {
   float: left;
}
.left {
   width: 100px;
   background-color: pink;
}
.middle {
   width: calc(100% - 200px);
   background-color: blue;
}
.right {
   width: 100px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>No flex</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Example using `flex`

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
}
.left {
   width: 100px;
   background-color: pink;
}
.middle {
   flex-grow: 1;
   background-color: blue;
}
.right {
   width: 100px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>Flex</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  In the no flex sample, you use `width: calc(100% - 200px)` 
Why does this work?  
Since you're only taking care of the left column in this case, why does the middle column not stretch to the end?

Comment: @n_1 I am not sure what do you mean. Left is `100px`, right is `100px` and middle is `100%` without left and without right - so `calc(100% - leftWidth - rightWidth)` which makes `100% - 200px`.

Answer (score 0):

`float: left;` and `float: right` can be used, but it has the following downsides:

1. The `middle` element needs to be used after the `right` element.
2. If elements height is relying on its content then all the elements' height will not be matched until you specify a fixed height. you can see a gray area which is the container in the below example.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  background: #33AFFF;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  background: #FFC300;
}
.middle {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  background: #FF5733;
}
```

```html
<h2>float</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left left left left left left left left left left </div>
  <div class="right">right right right right right </div>
  <div class="middle">middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle </div>
</div>

<div>Next element</div>
```

Or you can use `display: table` and it's children with `display: table-cell`.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%; 
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 150px;
  background: #33AFFF;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #FFC300;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 150px;
  background: #FF5733;
}
```

```html
<h2>display: table &amp; display: table-cell</h2>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left left left left left left left left left left</div>
  <div class="middle">middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle middle </div>
  <div class="right">right right right right right </div>
</div>

<div>Next element</div>
```